# I need client side to write to the server side

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, python-sockets

I'm trying to make the clients be able to send messages to the server, right now clients can only send messages to each other, I have added the line where datafromclient but it only receives the first input by the client, after that only the clients exchange messages.

here is my code for server.py

```
import socket
import threading

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(),1234))
s.listen()
print("Waiting for connections")

clients = []
unames = []

def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)

def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(message)
        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            uname = unames[index]
            broadcast(f"{uname} left the server!".encode("utf-8"))
            unames.remove(uname)
            break
def receive():
    while True:
        client, addr = s.accept()
        print(f"Connected with {str(addr)}")

        client.send('uname'.encode("utf-8"))
        uname = client.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        unames.append(uname)
        clients.append(client)

        broadcast(f"{uname} joined the server!".encode("utf-8"))
        client.send("\nWelcome to the server!".encode("utf-8"))
        fOpen = open("rules.txt", "r")
        client.send(fOpen.read().encode("utf-8"))

        datafromclient = client.recv(1024)
        print(datafromclient.decode("utf-8"))

        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()
receive()
s.close()
```

And this is client.py

```
import socket
import threading

c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c.connect((socket.gethostname(),1234))

uname = input("Username: ")

def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            message = c.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
            if message == "uname":
                c.send(uname.encode("utf-8"))
            else:
                print(message)
        except:
            print("An error occurred!")
            c.close()
            break

def write():
    while True:
        message = f'{uname}: {input("")}'
        c.sendall(message.encode("utf-8"))

recv_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
recv_thread.start()

write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you an idea:

server.py:

```
import socket
import threading

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 1234))

clients = []

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    clients.append(conn)
    while True:
        msg_length = conn.recv(64).decode("utf-8")
        if msg_length:
            msg = conn.recv(int(msg_length)).decode("utf-8")
            print(msg)
            if msg == "!DISCONNECT":
                break
            for client in clients:
                client.send(msg.encode("utf-8")) 
    clients.remove(conn)
    conn.send('Bye'.encode("utf-8")) 
    conn.close()

server.listen()
while True:
    conn, addr = server.accept()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
    thread.start()
```

client.py:

```
import socket
import threading

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 1234))

def send():
    msg = input(">>> ")
    client.send(str(len(msg)).encode("utf-8").ljust(64))
    client.send(msg.encode("utf-8"))

thread = threading.Thread(target=send)
thread.start()

while True:
    if client.recv(2048).decode("utf-8") == "Bye":
        break
    thread = threading.Thread(target=send)
    thread.start()
```